# SlidingPaneLayout - touch event is delegated to the view behind

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

How can I avoid that my SlidingPaneLayout delegates the touch event to the behind view?

In my case, if a non touchable area like a textview is over a button and the behind view is not visible and I touch the textview, the button get's the touch event...

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late, but for other people searching for the same issue:

I use

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

in the xml of the view that is non-touchable. For example, if you have a FrameLayout corresponding to the detail pane, then set its clickable value to true. Then it won't pass the touch events to the view behind(master pane).